# Sockets: send messages to several clients

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to write a server that accepts messages from multiple clients until it receives N of them, processes this batch of data and sends the reply "done" to all the clients.

This code works fine if I send the message "done" to a client right after I receive the data from the client. How can I "save" all the clients and send to each of them the message later, after the batch is processed?

```
while (true) {
    listen(sock, 1000);
    newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    n = read(newsock, buffer, read_len);
    if (n < 0) {
        cout << "ERROR reading from the socket" << endl;
        continue; 
    }
    memcpy(data + (msg_count * tuple_size), buffer, tuple_size);
    n = write(newsock, "done\n", 5); //sending the message to the current client
    msg_count++;
    if (msg_count >= batch_size) {
        msg_count = 0;
        doSomethingWithTheData(data);
        //I want to send the message to all the clients here
    }
    bzero(buffer, read_len);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting cookies?

Comment: @ArashMohammadi no, I haven't tried them, I'm going to read about it now. Would cookies work in case the server and all the clients are on the same PC?

Comment: If a client can send more than one message, you might want to look into `select` or `epoll`.

Comment: Currently there is only one message per client, a client can send the next message only for the next batch.

Comment: Also watch out: `read` makes no assurances that you get an entire message. You will receive between 0 and `read_len` bytes. `n` is the number of bytes actually read and 0 means socket disconnected. If `n` is less than the number of bytes you need for a message, you'll have to loop until you get the whole message.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the warning. :) Fortunately, the number of bytes in a message is relatively small and is the same for every client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```cpp
while (true) {
    std::list<int> socks;
    listen(sock, 1000);
    newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    n = read(newsock, buffer, read_len);
    if (n < 0) {
        cout << "ERROR reading from the socket" << endl;
        continue; 
    }
    memcpy(data + (msg_count * tuple_size), buffer, tuple_size);
    socks.push_back(newsock);
    msg_count++;
    if (msg_count >= batch_size) {
        msg_count = 0;
        doSomethingWithTheData(data);

        //I want to send the message to all the clients here
        msg_count -= socks.size();
        while (!socks.empty()) {
            newsock = socks.front();
            n = write(newsock, "done\n", 5); //sending the message to the current client
            close(newsock);
            socks.pop_front();
        }
    }
    bzero(buffer, read_len);
}
```

FYI The [bzero()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html) function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001): use memset(3) in new programs.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of bzero()

Comment: Correct. You will have to do something like this anyway, vgeclair, because currently you are only allocating socks without ever freeing them.

Comment: I just tried it, but it gives a "Broken pipe" error in this line: 
`n = write(sock, "done\n", 5);` 

Are you sure I should add `sock` to the list and not `newsock`? It seems to always have the same value.

Comment: You appear to be correct, @vgeclair . `sock` is the socket you're listening to, not the one that's connected to the client.

Comment: But if I add `newsock` instead, it just doesn't work (the values are different though) and the clients don't get the messages.

Comment: I was wrong, it works (if I replace `sock` with `newsock` and create the list before the loop), the problem was caused by something on the client side.
Thank you!

Comment: @vgeclair Sorry, it was my typo. I have edited my answer,

Answer (score -1):

Did you try zeroMq ? 
for example http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:rrworker

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. How would it help to remember several clients?

Comment: My idea was extend Request-Reply patter where 
n client connect to front-end socket and dispatch it to batch workers.
After workers finish their job front-end socket response to n client